# .htaccess redirect new domain and new url structure

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm setting up redirects from an old domain to new with a different URL structure. A couple of questions concerning the setup below.

First, will this capture both www and non www URLs as well as HTTP and HTTPS? Does the sufficiently redirect one URL from the old domain to the new domain with a URL structure change?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page-1/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/page-one [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page-2/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/page-two [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Second, I'd like to set up a rule that catches other unspecified redirects to redirect to the homepage. Would this work?

```
# catch all rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule . https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is unclear why you ask these questions. You can simply try out your rules and check yourself if they work or not.

Comment: Normally, that's exactly what I would do but it's a strange case. It's something that needs to be done prior to the launch of the new domain as there are several layers of teams that I have to go through to get it implemented. I don't have access so they have to implement it themselves. If there is a tool that tests this, that would be awesome! Is there a tool I can use to test them?

Comment: I discovered the Made With Love tester and believe I've figured it out.  https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds like the too-often-seen situation of lots of "professionals" not having a clue about what they claim to be experts in.

Comment: Sorry if I’m using this community incorrectly.  I’m not at all claiming to be a programming expert (and I would never make a claim as such because it’s untrue) - which is why I came here. The community had people asking questions in the same vein but not exactly my scenario. 

If nothing else, I hope someone looking for an answer similar to mine will now have a resource at their disposal.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am willing to help. But it is not really of any help for you if someone types some commands here and you copy&paste those. That is not how you have security that the solution actually works as you want. For that you need to test. You need to test yourself. Which is what I suggested. You said that is not possible because of "several layers of teams", which sounds like a company or multiple involved companies to me. Yet you also say that you have little experience with this stuff. Which triggered my comment above.

Comment: You certainly _can_ setup a test environment for this. You can simply use two systems where you hard code the host name resolution to points to the one system you use as server. There you can implement your rules and test if things work as expected. All you need to do there is setup a http server, configure a vhost for the host name ("domain") and start testing. That is the way to go. Only that way you actually reach the exact setup you want and can afterwards trust your own solution.